# AngularJS How to access Controller scope from Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

I am trying to access parent controller scope from a directive function. When I try to get the value of `$scope.$parent` it returns me the object. But when I try to access any variable from that object it returns ***Undefined***.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.init = function(){

        $http.get('url.php').success(function(data){
            $scope.assignmentInfo = data.record;
        });

    };
});


app.directive('getInfo', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            data:'=',
            title: '='
        },
        link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.$watch('data.visible', function(val){
                // do something

            });
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.$parent); // return an object

            console.log($scope.$parent.assignmentInfo); // return undefined


        },
        templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
}]);
```

First `console.log($scope.$parent)` return the following output: 
[image]

But `$scope.$parent.assignmentInfo` return `underfined`

How do I access the `assignmentInfo`?

Comment: try this way : http://jsfiddle.net/wZrjQ/1/

Comment: not what im trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is caused, by fact, that you try to print `assignmentInfo`, when it is not yet assigned, so you should `$watch` for it:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.assignmentInfo = 'some data';
    }, 1000)
}])
 .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      template: '<div>from directive: {{assignmentInfo}}</div>',
      controller: function($scope) {      
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          return $scope.$parent.assignmentInfo;
        }, function(value) {
          if (value){
            console.log(value);
            $scope.assignmentInfo = value;
          }
        })
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>    
  <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```